# Single or habitual obligation

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense

> I am to report this to the police.

What is the correct explanation of this sentence?

a) It is a single future obligation for me to report. (Like, I must report this to the police)

b) It is my regular obligation to report. (Like, I have to report this to the police every day)

Comment: I imagine, for that particular phrasing, it would be "single future obligation" *slightly* more often, but **it would always depend entirely on context** (can you provide any context?).

Comment: Is it possible to use "be to" as a regular or habitual obligation?

Comment: What @ChrisMack said. For example, the speaker could say *I am to report this to the police **next** Friday* or ***...every** Friday*. Although "this" (which isn't particularly likely in the cited context) would usually imply *one specific thing, to be reported on one occasion only*. Note that ***report*** is usually an intransitive verb for such contexts *(to report to the police = to **present oneself to / check in with** the police)*.

Comment: I am to report this to the police every day. or I have to report this to the police. Which one is more likely?

Comment: Hunter - you're confusing "more likely" ***situation*** with more likely ***phrasing***. Everything depends on the actual context.

Comment: I understood your explanation. Now please look at the sentence "She is to swim twice every week". Is it natural to you?

Comment: "She is to swim twice every week" - yes, this is perfect English, although might be simplified to "She is to swim twice **a** week".

Comment: She has to swim twice a week. She is to swim twice a week. Do they have any difference in meaning? @Chris

Comment: @Hunter: You should probably ask this in a new question - it's difficult to provide proper answers in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by Chris Mack says, the detailed meaning of this very short sentence depends on context, especially what the pronoun "this" refers to. The definition of what "this" refers to **may very well** be sufficient to determine whether a single report or multiple reports are required.

> The conditions of my release require me to submit my expected intinerary for the next calendar day no later than 8:00 P. M. I am to report this to the police.

clearly contemplates daily reports of a single type of thing, namely an itinerary.

> I asked my lawyer what I should do about what I saw. I am to report this to the police

seems to contemplate a single report of a single observation. Although there may be additional interactions with the police as a result, the obligation to report islikely singular.

Even with the referent of "this" specified, it may be unclear whether the obligation to report is singular or not although the use of a singular pronoun does imply that one thing or one type of thing is to be reported.

Pronouns have inherent ambiguity if they have no explicit referent.